# Correct Use of Dependency Injection and YAGNI confusion in C#

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I am aware that you should depend on abstractions not concrete implementations but I am also aware of the [YAGNI](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) principle. I sometimes find myself struggling to reconcile both of these.

Consider the following classes;

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoFoo()
    {
    }
    //private foo stuff
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public Bar()
    {
        _foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

"Bar" is the class I am interested in; obviously there is a problem, Bar is instantiating an instance of Foo, so let me refactor;

```
public class Bar
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Great, but Bar's constructor still depends on Foo, a concrete implementation. I haven't gained anything (have I?). To fix this I need to make foo an abstraction and this is where my problem begins.

Every example I ever find always (understandably) demonstrates constructor injection using abstractions. I'm all for programming defensively but lets presume I have no need for any other implementations except Foo (test doubles don't count). To create an "IFoo" interface or a "FooBase" abstract class surely violates the YAGNI principle? I would be making something for a possible future scenario and I can always do that later e.g.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract void DoFoo();

    //private foo stuff
}

public class Foo1:Foo
{
    public override void DoFoo()
    {
    }
}
```

This doesn't break Bar and I could even do this for an interface provided I dropped the "I" convention (which I grow ever more sceptical of) e.g.

```
public interface Foo
{
    void DoFoo();
}

public abstract class FooBase:Foo
{
    public abstract void DoFoo();

    //private foo stuff
}

public class Foo1:FooBase
{
    public override void DoFoo()
    {
    }
}
```

What is wrong with injecting a concrete implementation since I can refactor this to an abstraction at a later stage (provided I give the abstraction the same name as the concrete implementation)?

Note: I am aware of the arguments for the "I" interface naming convention and this is not the point of my question. I am also aware that making Foo an abstract class will break the code wherever I was previously instantiating it, but presume I am using DI extensively and so I would only need to change the DI container registration, something I would probably have to do anyway if I were to introduce a new implementation of Foo.

Comment: You can bind a class to itself in DI containers without creating a corresponding interface (just did this in Ninject). There is nothing wrong with it in my mind. Depends on the scale of the project!

Comment: #adaam - thanks for the response, why might scale be a factor? Were you thinking that larger projects are more likely to introduce new requirements that would result in new implementations?

Comment: To build on the point @adaam is making, another reason you'd want to have your concrete types supplied by a DI container is managing their lifecycle. If you're using objects that do not hold internal state, there's nothing explicitly wrong with passing them around as a singleton, especially if they have an expensive instantiation cost.

Comment: @mark_h Yes sorry phrasing was incorrect! I was referring to the number of applications of a module of code in a project. If you are designing a class for a single use application and you know it is unlikely that you will use it again, then there is little point interfacing it. I've learnt software development is just as much about being pragmatic as it is about designing by contract, and this extends to DI

Comment: @adaam actually using an interface gives you virtual methods which then can be mocked using a mocking framework so that you can isolate your unit tests. so it's not just on re-use but testability.

Comment: I disagree. Most mature DI frameworks allow you to specify the life time scope of each registered type so you can specify that a type is a singleton and pass it around using injection (as either type or interface). Also most types that are created will not be replaced by another instance directly but even here using DI has benefits. The benefits are that you think more about what you are building especially when it comes time to unit test, unit testing becomes infinity easier when you can mock a set of interfaces that are passed around instead of having to deal with a bunch of concrete ....

Comment: ^---  *continuation* types that are instantiated directly. What you usually end up with are better designed components that are more cohesive and loosely coupled.

Comment: @Fran Yes you can mock methods in a concrete class by marking them as virtual though. But i take your point - interfaces are easier for this (and better design).

Comment: I am a strong believer in unit testing, but isn't it bad to alter a class' public interface purely for the sake of unit testing bad practice?

Comment: @mark_h - I do not consider the constructor to be the public facing interface as these are not used directly only by the injection framework (not true for all types of course but it is for those that are registered).

Comment: @Igor, sorry if I wasn't clear. I wasn't talking about the Bar constructor. In order to make Bar more easily testable I may have to create a test double for Foo. In its original implementation this isn't possible because Foo doesn't have any seams. If I made the DoFoo method virtual I could override it in a derived class and create a test double.

Comment: @mark_h - yes, that would work. Whether you use interfaces or non-sealed classes with virtual methods seems like a whole different discussion. I always opt for interfaces (that is consuming the interface) and use inheritance on the type(s) behind the interface. That way the consumer still only knows about a contract and not a type (which can be more difficult to replace and possibly also to mock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but Bar's constructor still depends on Foo, a concrete implementation. I haven't gained anything (have I?).

What you gained here is that when the dependency `Foo` itself gets any dependencies of its own, or requires a different lifestyle, you can make this change without having to do sweeping changes throughout all consumers of `Foo`.

> I have no need for any other implementations except Foo (test doubles don't count)

You can't just ignore unit testing in this. As [Roy Osherove](http://osherove.com/) [explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290890) a long time ago, your test suite is another (equally important) consumer of your application with its own requirements. If adding the abstraction simplifies testing, you shouldn't need another reason for creating it.

> To create an "IFoo" interface or a "FooBase" abstract class surely violates the YAGNI principle?

You won't violate YAGNI if you create this abstraction for testing. In that case YNI (You need it). By not creating the abstraction you you are optimizing locally within your production code. This is a local optimum instead of a global optimum, since this optimization doesn't take all the other (equally important) code that needs to be maintained (i.e. your test code) into consideration.

> What is wrong with injecting a concrete implementation since I can refactor this to an abstraction

There isn't anything wrong per see to inject a concrete instance, although -as said- creating an abstraction *could* simplify testing. If it doesn't simplify testing and letting the consumer take a hard dependency on the implementation could be fine. But do note that depending on a concrete type can have its downsides. For instance, it becomes harder to replace it with a different instance (such as an interceptor or decorator) without having to make changes to the consumer(s). If this is not a problem, you might as well use the concrete type.

Comment: Your point about decorator is a good one! I was only thinking about a different implementation, not an extended one.

Comment: @Steven, in the first question of your answer, do you mean `Foo` instead of `Bar`?

Comment: @Steven, I think you might want to rephrase this statement: "You won't create YAGNI is you are actually testing", I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: @YacoubMassad: You're totally right. That didn't make any sense at all. I rephrased it.

Answer (score 2):

As adaam mentioned there is nothing wrong with doing what you want.

What DI Container are you using? If you are using Unity, PRISM has a pretty good example of how to register your ViewModels as BindableBase(Base class provided by PRISM) unless you have a base class that implements additional interfaces implemented.

Typically I have a BaseViewModel that extends BindableBase and implements INotifyDataErrorInfo and some otherinterfaces. Then when modules are being discovered, they register the ViewModels as types of BaseViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Providing `Foo` in constructor of `Bar` still gives you something compared to instantiating it inside `Bar`, even if just concrete implementaiton. Suppose you want to test your `Bar`, and suppose you designed `Foo` in a way that all functionality which might cause problems with unit testing is placed in virtual methods. Then in your unit test you inherit from `Foo`, override necessary members, and then pass instance of your inherited class to `Bar` constructor, which obviously would not be possible if you instantiated `Foo` inside `Bar` itself. Same story with DI - you can register class inherited from `Foo` as `Foo` in DI container.

Comment: I can see that unit testing Bar with an injected concrete implementation would be problematic because I couldn't easily mock it but I'm not comfortable with the idea of exposing virtual methods purely for the purposes of unit testing.

Comment: I don't say you should do this, but you said "I haven't gained anything" by providing Foo in constructor, and I think you actually did, because you _can_ (not _should_) provide different (inherited) implementation if necessary.

Comment: That's true, I have the option to refactor Foo to allow for testing (whether it be by virtual methods, abstract classes or an interface)